# Remove rows which nothing in more than one columns

Tags: r

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), text1 = c("sth","","another",""), text2 = c("more","another","add",""), text3 = c("final","and","where",""), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

How is it possible to check for text1, text2, text3 column if all of them have cells with nothing written how to remove it?

Example of expected output

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), text1 = c("sth","","another"), text2 = c("more","another","add"), text3 = c("final","and","where"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Try `df[rowSums(df == '') != (ncol(df) - 1),]`

Comment: At the risk of sounding like a broken record, it's *really* preferable if you include what you've tried that hasn't worked and/or what research you've done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rowSums`

```
df[rowSums(df == '') < 2, ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
cols <- paste0("text", 1:3)
df[rowSums(df[cols] == "") < length(cols), ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another base R solution using `nchar` + `rowSums`

```
subset(df,rowSums(nchar(as.matrix(df[-1])))>0)
```

such that

```
  id   text1   text2 text3
1  1     sth    more final
2  2         another   and
3  3 another     add where
```

Comment: Nice solution but I would say using something like `> 0` is better practice than coercing with `!` just to add another `!`.

Comment: @sindri_baldur thanks, I will change it to `>0`, rather than using `!!`

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion solution using `dplyr`:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4),
           text1 = c("sth","","another",""),
           text2 = c("more","another","add",""),
           text3 = c("final","and","where",""),
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  filter_at(vars(starts_with("text")), any_vars(!. %in% c("")))
```

Returns:

```
  id   text1   text2 text3
1  1     sth    more final
2  2         another   and
3  3 another     add where
```